# React router gives "redirect to the same route" error

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have got routes like below and I want to redirect users to admin/users page if someone clicks ADMIN button (this button routes to /admin) on the home page but I get this error:

> You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on:
>   /admin/users

```
<Switch location={this.props.location}>
     <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
     <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
     <Route path="/account" component={Account} />

     <Route path="/admin/users" component={Users} />
     <Route path="/admin/auth" component={Auth} />

     <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/users" />

     <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
</Switch>
```

- I added location attribute into Switch because I use animations while routing. You can find an example at this link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions
- If I remove location attribute everything is fine but with this attribute I get errors.
- I searched lots of sites and tried several things but I could not achieve. I need location attribute, I cannot remove it.

If you help I will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can u try removing `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` ? This one may overrides previous routes

Comment: No, sorry. I still have the same error. The code like below:

`<Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/users" />

{/* <Redirect from="*" to="/" /> */}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only achieve if I write the below code:

```
<Route exact strict path="/admin" render={({location}) => {
    if (location.pathname === window.location.pathname) {
         return <Redirect to="/admin/users" />;
    }
    return null;
}} />
```

But why does Switch not prevent to run the below redirect route again and again? Because when the redirect happens, 
*/admin/users* route works but also */admin* route works too. Why does Switch not prevent? Does anybody have an answer for this?

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but will remove the error.

```
<Switch location={this.props.location}>
 <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
 <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} />
 <Route path="/account" component={Account} />

 <Route path="/admin/users" component={Users} />
 <Route path="/admin/auth" component={Auth} />

 {allowedToRedirect
  ?(
    <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/users" />

    <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
   )
  : null}
</Switch>
```

Where `const allowedToRedirect = location.pathname === window.location.pathname;`
https://codesandbox.io/s/pjk4ykr4kq

Comment: Well, since i can not comment other messages but mine - can not reply to your new answer to your own question (which is exactly the same as mine for some reason).
Its is like that because the way transitions work. They take old props for old view and new props for new view. Since you already redirected to new page, redirect with old props (location) throws such error.